# Chat reply in Inbox shows @@ID instead of a proper username

Tags: bug, chat, global-inbox, super-ping

Here is the message which I've received it yesterday (ignore the content):

[image]

and I didn't open ignoring it, because I thought these numbers were some mistake or some kind of bug (in addition to 'chat reply' which was confusing, as I wasn't on any chat).

But when I got another similar message today, I've clicked on it and my username was there (in place of the numbers).

So I'm basically requesting fixing the bug (the username not appearing in the chat reply), as it's quite confusing to who the message is addressed to.

Comment: The `@@` is a superping, a mod-only feature available for pinging users who aren't in chat.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, but obviously there shouldn't be a number in Inbox. In chat it-self, the nickname is appearing as expected.

Comment: I was gonna report this bug too; thanks for bringing it up. In principle the message content is correct since we pinged you by ID, but it should be replaced or removed entirely before delivering the notification.